# changing button text on mouseover, resizes entire button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an annoying problem, I want the bootstrap button to be fixed in size. At the moment when I scroll over the bootstrap button it resizes the entire button. I use javascript to change the text (mouseover and mouseout). How can I disable this so the button remains the same size and only the text changes?

**Example button:**

```
<button type='button' id='Warning' class='btn btn-warning btn-block text-left' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal'>Pending</button>
```

**Javascript:**

```
    $('body').on('mouseover', '#Success', function (e) {
        $(this).removeClass("btn-success");
        $(this).addClass("btn-danger");
        $(this).text('Deactivate?');
    });
    $('body').on('mouseover', '#Warning', function (e) {
        $(this).removeClass("btn-warning");
        $(this).addClass("btn-success");
        $(this).text('Activate?');
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the visible width of the 2 text labels is different, the button has to change size to accommodate the text.

You should set a fixed size of the button via CSS that is big enough to fit either text label:

```
#Warning {
    width: 200px;
}
```

Without seeing more of your markup, it's difficult to know how this affects other layout elements.

You could try giving the button an `auto` margin in the horizontal:

```
#Warning {
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Or it might be that you need to explicitly center the buttons in it's container:

```
.class-name-of-the-buttons-parent-container {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: This fixes the issue, however because the buttons are nested inside a datatable. It seems to drag the button to the left and leaves a gap on the right side of the column it is nested in?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest giving the button a fixed width that's enough for both states and removing the horizontal paddings. Optionally you can give it `text-align:center`

Answer (score 1):

Freeze the button's width and height during the mouseover event.  Also, set its padding to 0 to keep the text centered:

```js
$('body')
  .on('mouseover', '#Warning', function (e) {
    $(this).css({
      width: $(this).outerWidth(),
      height: $(this).outerHeight(),
      padding: 0
    });
    $(this).text('Activate?');
  })
  .on('mouseout', '#Warning', function (e) {
    $(this).text('Pending');
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='Warning'>Pending</button>
```

Comment: This adds the gap on mouseover. After mouseout it doesnt go back either.

Answer (score 0):

You should add an additional CSS class that overrides the Bootstrap defaults to the button. Something like ...

```
.fixed_size_button {
    width: 200px;
}
```

In some cases you might need to add !important to actually override prior CSS settings, especially since Bootstrap itself uses a lot of !important statements. E.g.

```
.fixed_size_button {
    width: 200px !important;
}
```

But you should avoid this as much as possible since it is difficult to maintain.

Comment: While your solution would work, I must **strongly** recommend **against** using `!important`.  That's what CSS specificity is for.

Comment: Agreed. However sometimes it is necessary if you use a complex CSS framework and want to leave the original CSS code untouched. I ran into such cases using Bootstrap. However, it might not be necessary here.

Comment: In that case you would just make your CSS statement *more specific*.  At minimum, you could tie in specificity, then just ensure your stylesheet is loaded after the CSS frameworks.

Comment: This down vote is unfair. Since the Bootstrap CSS code uses !important all over the place it might be indeed necessary to use !important in order to restore the usual resolution order even if the custom CSS is loaded after Bootstrap.